# Can't get cookies when logging in through a Python script

Tags: session, cookies, python-requests, authorization

Tell me, please, I do not quite understand why it is not possible to get cookies when requested through a script. After authorization, there should, in theory, be cookies, I think it would be possible to remember and send them in the next request, so that the authorized user is then passed through the script to the account and to other closed (inaccessible for unauthorized users) pages each time. Cookies are received through the browser, but not through running a script that simulates sending data from a form. I get empty cookies: <RequestsCookieJar []>

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
 
url = https://proza.ru/cgi-bin/login/intro.pl' # form data handler address
ua = UserAgent()
session = requests.Session()
responce = session.post(
        url, {
                'block': '',
                'username': 'somelogin',
                'password': 'somepassword',                
        },  headers = {
                'User-Agent': ua.chrome,                
        })
 
print(responce.cookies) # I get empty cookies: <RequestsCookieJar []>
print (responce.status_code) # 200
print (responce.headers)

#{'Server': 'QRATOR', 'Date': 'Fri, 21 Aug 2020 08:41:50 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=windows-1251', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=15', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}

 
# Then I thought of doing something like this request for closed pages each time so that authorization would not be lost:

session.get('https://proza.ru/2018/03/07/…', cookies=responce.cookies)
```

Comment: I think you should check what is the response, by printing (and rendering) `responce.text`. Maybe that is coming out to be some error? Do let us know what happens.

Comment: @Mooncrater `with open("account_success.html","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(responce.text)` If I execute this line, then the full valid html-code of the authorization page is returned, but then I go to other pages as an unauthorized user, again.

Comment: There is the part of code html-form for the authorization page: `<form method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/login/intro.pl" name="loginform">
<input type="hidden" name="block" value=""><input type="text" size="10" class="butt" style="width:100px" name="login" value=""><input type="password" size="10" class="butt" name="password" maxlength="15" style="width:100px">`

Comment: I do not know why, but the server does not return the "set-cookie" header when requesting my script. Maybe my request fails authorization. But almost always, cookies are set even by unauthorized users. However, I have no cookies.

Comment: Get the form information, find all the inputs that have a name, inside the form. You might be missing some important input.